# NEXTJS Sending formdata to api endpoint - no response

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, form-data

Hellooooo.

I am trying to upload images to AWS S3 and I've stumbled upon something that irritates me quite a lot. I simply can't seem to understand why it would act like this.

Aight so.. I am using formdata to send data to my api endpoint. The API gets called without any issues, no errors, nothing.. Like srly, nothing. Before getting to image upload I was just using a basic body post request with fetch but now I am using formdata in order to upload images.

Here's my "fetch/axios/sendthingy"

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', validFiles[0]);
formData.append('postTitle', postTitle);
formData.append('postProduct', postProduct);
formData.append('postDescription', postDescription);
formData.append('postPrice', postPrice);
formData.append('postCoins', cryptocoins);
formData.append('postCategory', Cate);
formData.append('postSubCategory', subCat);
formData.append('postCryptoDiscount', cryptoDiscount);
            

for (const entry of formData.entries())
{
   // debugging
   console.log(entry)
}

var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json"); // or form data?

const requestOptions = {
     method: 'POST',
     body: formData,
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, // or use myHeaders
     // body: JSON.stringify({ postTitle: postTitle, postProduct: postProduct, postDescription: postDescription, postPrice: postPrice, postCoins: cryptocoins, postImage: validFiles[0], postCategory: Cate, postSubCategory: subCat, postCryptoDiscount: cryptoDiscount})
};

// const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/posts/create`, requestOptions)
// const data = await res.json();

axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/posts/create', formData).then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

My comments are from before using formdata. That worked.

As you can see, I have installed Axios. I wanted to see if axios would fix the return stuff. No luck. Any ideas on how to solve this or how to send images to api with or without formdata?

Right, **let's move on**. Next issue is that I can see it calling my API endpoint but my api endpoint does nothing. It returns nothing. Does nothing. But when I call the api from postman it works just as it should. How come? It creates the post and returns the correct data. Any ideas?

My API:

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {

    console.log('body', req.body);

    /*
        Redacted
    */

    res.status(200).json({response: 'test', code: 200, message:"Successfully created the post."})
})
```

Why is my API not doing anything locally... It will only work with formdata if I call the endpoint from postman.

This is what I mean.. The dark one is Firefox, white is Postman:
[image: lmao]

Comment: I'd like to use my site to send the calls to the endpoint and not postman. I need to test image uploads and for what I know, postman cant do such things. ANyways, it would be way better if I could actually debug etc.. on my site and not on some thirdparty.

Comment: What headers are you sending in the Postman request? Try sending the same ones in your `fetch` call.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly , you should use `multipart/form-data` for uploading files. And to see the response you have to `console.log` the response like this:

```js
axios.post(
'http://localhost:3000/api/posts/create',
 formData,
 {headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}}
 ).then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: The response from the API is still empty. I tried but without any luck :-/